# Why to use Event grid for http trigger function?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-eventgrid

I am designing Http trigger function. This function will be used to authenticate and to call an external API. Then get the response and pass it on to the caller(~in this case web application).
This function can be called thousand time/min(~during peak load).

I am going through event grids and having hard time deciding why to use it.
Microsoft says to safeguard your events so that it's not lost due to any reason I should use it along with my http trigger azure function.

I can very well design a queue trigger function which will process these requests in queue.

I am referring to this article of MS which says to use Event grid to gain more control on your serverless function for example:
[MS Event Grid](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/events-data-points-and-messages-choosing-the-right-azure-messaging-service-for-your-data/?WT.mc_id=AZ-MVP-4021705)

Comment: If you put the information in the queue, it also will not be lost, will it? I think you need to follow your actual needs. It is not necessary to use event grid. The event grid is time-based and discrete. You  can also use other ways but If you use a queue, it is not event-based.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am going through event grids and having hard time deciding why to
> use it.
>
> I can very well design a queue trigger function which will process
> these requests in queue.

I think this needs to be based on your needs. The event grid is discrete based on event triggers. And event grid has higher scalability.

If you use a queue trigger, it is not triggered based on an event, is it? All in all, it is not necessary to use event grid. Please refer to your use case for specific use.

Comment: I agree once you put info in queue we loose event information.

Comment: @winterishere If you dont have more doubts, can we end this question now?

Answer (score 0):

If you want a comparison study of the messaging services you may refer to : https://tsuyoshiushio.medium.com/azure-messaging-service-in-a-picture-f8113cec54cd

https://hackernoon.com/azure-functions-choosing-between-queues-and-event-hubs-dac4157eee1c

[image]

For event grid, Azure Event Grid is an eventing service for the cloud. Azure Functions is one of the supported event handlers.

> Azure Event Grid allows you to easily build applications with event-based architectures. First, select the Azure resource you would like to subscribe to, and then give the event handler or WebHook endpoint to send the event to. Event Grid has built-in support for events coming from Azure services, like storage blobs and resource groups. Event Grid also has support for your own events, using custom topics. [reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/overview#:%7E:text=Event%20Grid%20connects%20your%20app,data%20anywhere%2C%20without%20writing%20code.)